# Is it possible to Pandas vectorize for operation involving a condition of a range of slice data?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

In this operation, the `array` was sliced over a `range`.
Such that, given the array

```
arr = np.array([.1, .11, .21, .01, .5, .7, .91, .92, .95, .96, .1, .21, .23, .6, .7, .71, .72, .95, 0.96, 0.97])
```

and a range of values,

#### Step 1

```
drange = np.arange(start_, end_)
```

The slicing was conducted as below

#### Step 2

```
select_val = arr[drange]
```

Then the `select_val` was check for values larger than a threshold, `th`.

#### Step 3

```
bool_data = select_val<th
```

Finally, using `argmin` to return the indices of the minimum values along an axis.

#### Step 4

```
doutput = np.argmin(bool_data)
```

In my case, the variable `start_`, `end_` was stored in a Pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(s=[1, 10], e=[12, 19]))
```

whereas, the arr is as of `Numpy` type.

Currently, I employ Pandas' `apply` to a function which compress all the steps 1-4:

```
def fx(arr, st, en, th):

    return np.argmin(arr[np.arange(st, en)] < th)
```

However, is it possible to employ a *vectorization* approach instead?

The code of the current strategy is as below:

```
def fx(arr, st, en, th):

    return np.argmin(arr[np.arange(st, en)] < th)

 th = 0.9
 np.random.seed(0)

 arr = np.array([.1, .11, .21, .01, .5, .7, .91, .92, .95,  # 8 select 6 range: 1-12
                  .96, .1, .21, .23, .6, .7, .71, .72, .95, 0.96, 0.97])     # Select 15 range 10-17


 df = pd.DataFrame(dict(s=[1, 10], e=[12, 19]))

 df['opt'] = df.apply(lambda x: fx(arr, x['s'], x['e'], th), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### NumPy broadcasting

```
m1 = arr[:, None] > th
ix = np.arange(len(arr))[:, None]
m2 = (ix >= list(df.s)) & (ix < list(df.e))

df['opt'] = np.argmax(m1 & m2, axis=0) - df.s
```

Result

```
    s   e  opt
0   1  12    5
1  10  19    7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative albeit not vectorize,

```
df['opt'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: np.argmin(arr[x['s']:x['e']] <th), axis=1)
```

But, potential issue is it very difficult to handle exception error in this form.